# ngtemplate-loader: relativeTo parameter is not using to resolve template path [angularjs], [webpack], [ngtemplate-loader]

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm a bit confused by [ngtemplate-loader](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader), I'll try to set up a very straightforward config where all my HTML files are located into a templates folder (see the folder structure below). Thus if I have correctly understood the way this module works, I defined the following config:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
     test: /\.html$/,
     use: [
         {
             loader: 'ngtemplate-loader?relativeTo=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, '../templates')),
        }
    ]
}
```

**Folder structure**

```
.
├── app
├── templates
└── ...
```

When I try to require my `templates/root.html` from my angular entry point `app/main.js` with the following command:

```
const rootTpl = require('root.html');
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'root.html' in '[__dirname]/app'
```

I don't understand why it tries to resolve the path of my `root.html` from `/app` instead of `/templates`.
Any idea about what is wrong with my configuration? Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using angular 1.5.11, webpack 3.10.0 and ngtemplate-loader 2.0.1.